# Transform detached MultiLineString to LineString by adding connection lines between each line segment in PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I have `MulitLineString`s that may consist of several detached lines like these three:

[image]

What I need is to transform it to a `LineString`. For my use case it would be the best strategy if I could connect the lines with the shortest connection line between each other so that I would get this:

[image]

I was thinking of using a combination of `ST_Dump()` and `ST_ShortestLine()` but was wondering if there may be another hack to do that.

Comment: I think you will at first have to group the lines by directionality, this will at least help you fill up the gaps between lines with the same direction. If you know that 1 and 2 "belong together" you could determine the points furthest apart, make a line, and then use something like st_difference to fill up the missing part. Once these are found and you want to connect 3 to the now merged 1+2 you could make all possibly connections and throw away those that intersect with anything but the street (you will have to use OSM for this).

Comment: as a start, you could dump the multilinestrings to linestrings and assign a unique id, then get the endpoints (st_startpoint, st_endpoint).  Then find closest pairs of points within your search distance that don't have matching ids (keep the closest pair per linestring id).  then st_makeline with the point pairs, keeping track of the linestring ids the points came from.  Then union the linestrings plus the new lines by grouping/joining by linestring_id_1 OR linestring_id_2.  If you come up with a solution you should post it as an answer. it's a good puzzle.